# Mathematica does not compute derivative of composite function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was checking some stuff from my Mechanics Course (non-inertial systems) using Mathematica and I realized I can't get it to compute the second derivative with respect to time.

If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be really thankful.

The problem appears when I try to calculate `a[t]` with the following code:

```
gamma[t_] = c t {Cos[w*t], Sin[w*t]}
```

> {c t Cos[t w], c t Sin[t w]}

```
v[t_] = Dt[gamma[t], {t, 1}, Constants -> {w, c}]
```

> {c Cos[t w] - c t w Sin[t w], c t w Cos[t w] + c Sin[t w]}

```
a[t_] = Dt[gamma[t], {t, 2}, Constants -> {w, c}]
```

> {-c t w^2 Cos[t w] - 2 c w Sin[t w], 2 c w Cos[t w] - c t w^2 Sin[t w]}

```
2 Dt[gamma[t], t, Constants -> {w, c}] - (w^2)*t*gamma[t]
```

> {-c t^2 w^2 Cos[t w] + 2 (c Cos[t w] - c t w Sin[t w]), -c t^2 w^2 Sin[t w] + 2 (c t w Cos[t w] + c Sin[t w])}

Comment: Welcome to the _Mathematica_ StackExchange. As a note for the future, it's general preferred for you to post your actual code if at all possible, rather than images or screenshots of your code. It makes it easier for us to copy and paste your code into _Mathematica_ and try to fix it, rather than needing to retype it. I transcribed the code from your screenshot, but it's possible I made a mistake, so please check it over for correctness.

Comment: Also, I must admit, I am a bit confused as to what the problem here is. At first glance, `a[t]`'s definition does appear to be the second derivative of `gamma[t]` already. Were you expecting a different answer? Is it related to the fourth line of code you had provided?

Comment: Since none of the other parameters depend on time, you can just as easily use `D` rather than `Dt` and save having to write `Constants -> {w, c}`. But I agree with eyorble: Your code is correctly computing the second derivative, so why exactly do you think it's not?

Comment: Hello, I was trying to demonstrate that a[t] es equal to the last equation (an it is). D actually differentiates w and c as functions of t, and Dt doesn't compute the derivative that appears from the product in ctwSin[wt].

Comment: it really doesn't make any sense, I'd perfectly do this by hand. but I'm worried that I can't get mathematica to do this